# Electrical diagram

Tags: diagrams, circuitikz

This is the sheme i've made :

[image]

And the code is:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[european]
\draw (0,0) to[sV,l_=$u_G$] (0,2.7) to[generic,l=$R_G$,i_=$i_{ul}$](2.5,2.7) to[generic,l_=$h_{ie1}$,i=$i_{b1}$] (5.2,2.7) to[short] (7.9,2.7);
\draw(2,2.7) 
(1.45,2.2) to [short] (1.45,2.2) node[anchor=west] {+}
(1.55,0.45) to [short] (1.55,0.45) node[anchor=west] {-};
\node at (1.7,1.35) {$u_{ul}$};
\draw(2.5,2.7)node[above=0.0cm]{$B_1$}  to [generic,l={$R_{B1}$},*-] (2.5,0);
\draw(5.2,0)node[below]{$C_1$} to[american current source,l=$h_{fe} i_{b1}$, *-*] (5.2,2.7)node[above=0.0cm]{$E_1$};
\draw(6.55,2.7) to [generic,l=$R_{E1}$,i=$i_{e1}$] (6.55,0);
\draw(7.9,2.7) node[above=0.0cm]{$B_2$} to[generic,l=$R_{B2}$,i=$i_{B2}$](7.9,0) ;
\draw(7.9,2.7) to [generic,l_=$h_{ie2}$, *-*,i=$i_{b2}$] (10.6,2.7)node[above=0.0cm]{$E_2$} ;
\draw(10.6,2.7) to [generic,l=$R_{E2}$,i=$i_{e2}$,-*](10.6,0)node[below]{$C_2$};
\draw(12.85,2.7) to[generic,l_=$R_{C2}$](12.85,0);
\draw(12.85,2.7) to(14.2,2.7)to [generic,l_=$R_{p}$,i=$i_{iz}$](14.2,0);
\draw(12.85,2.7) to[american current source,l=$h_{fe} i_{b2}$](10.6,2.7);
\draw(15,2.7) 
(14.8,2.2) to [short] (14.8,2.2) node[anchor=west] {+}
(14.9,0.45) to [short] (14.9,0.45) node[anchor=west] {-};
\node at (15.05,1.35) {$u_{iz}$};
\draw (0,0)--(14.2,0);
\draw[red,dashed,thick,rounded corners,-latex] (2.9,1.55)--([shift={(0.9,-0.5)}]2,2.7)-- ([shift={(-0.5,-0.5)}]10.6,2.7)--
([shift={(-0.5,0.5)}]10.6,0)-- ([shift={(0.5,0.5)}]2.4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

How could I move the `i_{iz}` part so it'll be like here

[image]

Comment: Like this, as described in the manual: `i>^=$i_{iz}$`

Comment: this is a variation on [How to draw electrical scheme](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220225/579) which has been determined to be a homework question (comment on [Circuitikz: drawing Electrical diagram (duplicate)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220826/579))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I won't do your homework for you, but I can help to explain the positioning of currents in `circuitikz`, which should help you complete assignments like this in the future.

A complete location spec for current labels is comprised of

- one of `^`/`_` to specify the position of the label above/below the component (where above and below is from the point of view of a component drawn from left-to-right), and
- one of `>`/`<` to specify the direction of the current towards/opposing the drawing direction of the component.

The order of the symbols determines whether the current is placed before or after the component: if the direction specifier comes first, the current is drawn *before* the component in the path, while if the direction specifier is last, the current is drawn *after* the component in the path.

The default location spec for currents is `^>`. In the absence of either specifier, its default will be used.

This short example should give an illustration of all the possibilities:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\newcommand{\labeltest}[2]{\draw (#1) to[generic,i#2=$i_1$] +(0,2);}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \labeltest{0,0}{} % default position (no specification)
  \labeltest{1,0}{^>} % current in drawing direction (up), current after component, label above (if drawn left-to-right)
  \labeltest{2,0}{_>} % current in drawing direction, current after component, label below
  \labeltest{3,0}{^<} % current opposes drawing direction, current after component, label above
  \labeltest{4,0}{_<} % current opposes drawing direction, current after component, label below
  \labeltest{5,0}{>^} % current in drawing direction, current before component, label above
  \labeltest{6,0}{>_} % current in drawing direction, current before component, label below
  \labeltest{7,0}{<^} % current opposes drawing direction, current before component, label above
  \labeltest{8,0}{<_} % current opposes drawing direction, current before component, label below
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]