# Drawing electrical diagram using circuitikz!

Tags: diagrams

I looked at the documentation and examples on CTAN, but `circuitikz` is hard to get the hang of.
[this http://prntscr.com/f8s0pz](http://prntscr.com/f8s0pz)

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please have a look at our [Help Center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help) to see [what type of questions should be avoided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). This question, e.g., looks like a "Please do it for me" question. But we prefer "Please help me to do it myself" questions. So you should show us a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that shows what you already have and what your concrete problem is.

Comment: I am new to this forum,i have done some work but i cant do a lot of things on this diagram so i commed hire for help.

Comment: That's ok. I (and @Schweinebacke) just tried to give you information about what is expected here. I suggest to read the linked information and update the question afterwards.

Comment: i expected to get help.

Answer (score 10):

In the spirit of "helping you to help yourself", here is a part of that diagram which (I think) contains all the elements and code snippets you will need to complete it yourself. Don't forget to read the comments in the code.

### Result

[image: result]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
% I use a tikzpicture instead of a circuitikz here because
% the standalone package does weird things with the paper
% size when using a circuitikz environment. Feel free to
% change this in your document.
% We choose a base length of 3cm to simplify our coordinate
% calculations. Adjust as needed. Default is 1cm by the way.
%\begin{circuitikz}[x=3cm,y=3cm]
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm,y=3cm]
    % Define all coordinates. Not strictly necessary, but it
    % makes for cleaner code, in my humble opinion.
    \coordinate[label=below:$+$]   (INP) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label=$A_1$]       (A1)  at (1,0);
    \coordinate[label=$B_1$]       (B1)  at (2,0);
    \coordinate                    (C1)  at (1,-1);
    \coordinate                    (CE1) at (2,-1);
    \coordinate[label=above:$-$]   (INN) at (0,-1);
    \coordinate[label=$D_1$]       (D1)  at (3,0);
    \coordinate                    (L1)  at (3,-1);

    % Draw part of the circuit. You might need more than one
    % draw command, depending on how you do things.
    \draw 
        (INP) to[short,o-*,i_=$i_{ul}$]                (A1)
              to[R,l_=$R_1$,-*,i^>=$i_2$]              (B1)
              to[C,l_=$C_{E1}$,-*,i^>=$i_{e1}$]        (CE1)
              --                                       (C1)
              to[C,l_=$C_1$,*-*,i<^=$i_1$]             (A1)
        (INN) to[short,o-]                             (C1)
        (B1)  to[I,i_<=$gi_1$,color=orange]            (D1)
              to[L,l_=$L_1$,color=magenta,i=$i_4$,*-*] (L1)
              --                                       (CE1)
    ;

    % Some additional labelling...
    \node at (0,-0.5) {$u_{ul}$};

    % Helper lines
    % Remove the 'dashed' parameter for a normal line.
    % This part uses the 'calc' library from TikZ for
    % coordinate calculations.
    % NOTE: The corner radius has to be adjusted manually
    %       if you adjust the base x and y lengths in the
    %       optional argument for the tikzpicture/circuitikz
    %       environment.
    \draw[red,dashed,rounded corners=0.2cm,-latex]
           ($(INP) + ( 0.175,-0.5  )$) 
        -- ($(INP) + ( 0.175,-0.175)$) 
        -- ($(B1)  - ( 0.175, 0.175)$)
        -- ($(CE1) + (-0.175, 0.175)$) 
        -- ($(INN) + ( 0.175, 0.175)$)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

### Syntax Remarks

Since `circuitikz`'s syntax is admittedly a bit terse and can look rather cryptic to the uninitiated, a few remarks on that:

`to[short,o-*,i_=$i_{ul}$]`

`short` will just draw a line (or, as the name implies, a short-circuit). `o-*` means to draw a non-filled circle on the starting point (in this case, on the left side of the element), and a filled circle on the terminating side. Note that if you draw from left to right, this would obviously be flipped. `i_=text` places an arrowhead for a current in the middle of the line, labelled with `text`, *below* the arrow due to the underscore. By default, the label would go above the arrow (`i=text`), and you can also place something above the arrow explicitly via `i^=text`.

`to[C,l_=$C_{E1}$,-*,i^>=$i_{e1}$]`

draws a capacitor, labelled with `$C_{E1}$`. By default, the label would go on the right side of the capacitor (or, for `TikZ`, "above") because we're drawing from top to bottom in this case. We place it on the left side by placing an underscore before the `=`, as above. Also note that for the left capacitor, we also place the label "below" the element, but because we're drawing from bottom to top in that case, the label ends up on the right side.

Same as with the `short`, we add a current via `i^>=$i_{e1}$`. The `^` places the label on the right side (as said above, it's not strictly needed though), the `>` indicates the direction of the arrow, and the order `^>` means that the current arrow should be drawn after the capacitor (whereas `>^` would place the arrow above the capacitor CE1 in this case). See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222125/131649).

And if you're wondering what that whole `to[]` thing is about: That's a TikZ operator. It's basically a fancy version of the `--` path operator (which just draws a line), allowing for more customization. See Section 14.13 in the PGF manual, on page 157 in its current version.