# Electrical Circuits with Current Direction and Active Part

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits, tikz-circuit-lib

I am working in a power electronic circuit that works on several modes. For different mode different parts are active and current directions are different.I saw some similar papers in IEEE Xplore. Is there any way to draw the circuits like this in latex(I mean the current direction in dotted line and elements of the 
active part is faded like in the picture )?[image]

Comment: Maybe help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370178/31034

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Thanks ferahfeza. your link helped me a lot. Since I am new to latex, I have little experience. Also Thanks Tiuri. Next time I will add the specific code in which I am facing problem. Thanks for your suggestion